# jQuery slider: pause on hover - how?

Tags: jquery, hover, slider

I am using the following [jQuery slider](http://codepen.io/andyunleash/pen/vzGjq) (original source).

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfp0yfgq/)

Both links provide better documanted code as opposed to pasted code below.

**PROBLEM**
What's the code to make the slideshow pause on hover and resume it again when the mouse leaves it.

**CODE**

```
function slideOut(element, looping) { 
          if(looping != null) { 
              $slide = element; 
          } else { 
              $slide = $(element).find(">:first-child");
          }
          $slide
              .delay(interval)
              .fadeOut(fadeTime, slideIn);
      } 

      function slideIn() { 
          var $nextSlide = $(this).next(); 
          if ($nextSlide.length == 0) { 
              $firstSlide = $(this).parent().find(">:first-child"); 
              $firstSlide.fadeIn(fadeTime); 
              slideOut($firstSlide, true); 
          } else {
              $nextSlide.fadeIn(fadeTime); 
              slideOut($nextSlide, true); 
          } 
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a mouse enters, you should clear the interval:

```
$('//text here').mouseenter(function(){
   clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
});
```

When a mouse leaves, you should restart the interval:

```
$('//text here').mouseleave(function(){
    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
});
```

Read more about [JQuery mouse events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

Comment: Thanks :) I've found this before but I don't know how to implement this into existing code.